# Play fairplay m3u8 with licence url

Tags: http-live-streaming, azure-media-services, m3u8, fairplay, bento

I'm trying to play the stream on VLC Media Player, i'm putting manually the licence url, I've replaced `skd://licence` to fair play licence url: `https://examplelicence.keydelivery.brazilsouth.media.azure.net/FairPlay/?KID=945c7737-5c53-4b64-abd9-XXXXXXXXf87a`

But it still doesn't play, am i doing something wrong? or do i need to do something else?

This is how my M3U8 is:

```
#EXTM3U
#-----------------------------------------------------------
#--Created with VSPP Streamer version 5.2.6.1 build  Commit_id: c33916f2ac254d5ffe3aebe13d60f00ddb9c1cf2 Commit_time: 1582294933 context DINLDCAAKKCCADBG
#-----------------------------------------------------------
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2021-09-17T22:48:57.902Z
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:692919
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES,URI="skd://licence",KEYFORMAT="com.apple.streamingkeydelivery",KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1"
#EXTINF:2.002,
Level(7000000)/Segment(16319189379018560).ts
#EXTINF:2.002,
Level(7000000)/Segment(16319189399038560).ts
#EXTINF:2.002,
Level(7000000)/Segment(16319189419058560).ts
#EXTINF:2.002,
Level(7000000)/Segment(16319189439078560).ts
#EXTINF:2.002,
Level(7000000)/Segment(16319189459098560).ts
#EXTINF:2.002,
Level(7000000)/Segment(16319189479118560).ts
#EXTINF:2.002,
Level(7000000)/Segment(16319189499138560).ts
#EXTINF:2.002,
Level(7000000)/Segment(16319189519158560).ts
#EXTINF:2.002,
Level(7000000)/Segment(16319189539178560).ts
#EXTINF:2.002,
Level(7000000)/Segment(16319189559198560).ts
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You are doing it wrong.  VLC does not support Apple Fairplay DRM at all.
You can only use Apple Fairplay DRM on an iOS device using the native AvPlayer framework.

Try removing the DRM and trying VLC again.  I'm not aware of any support in VLC player for DRM? You may need to reach out to VLC directly on that issue - but I have not seen any support for Widevine in their players either.

If you are trying to test playback, use a browser based player that supports Widevine, Playready, or the native AvPlayer framework on iOS, or use the ExoPlayer for Android.
Also check out HLS.js, Shaka Player, Theo Player, JW Player, Bitmovin player and others for options on playback of DRM content in a browser.